# simple method to detect node crashes

Tags: ros-hydro, ubuntu-precise, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey guys,

I am searching for a simple way to detect a node crash. I saw [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/206077/crash-detection/) already and the answer looks pretty simple to implement. However, the project I am working on has around 15+ nodes running at the same time and it looks like I would have to set a watchdog for each one of them.

Since the master does provide a message in the terminal whenever a node has crashed I was wondering if there is not an even more simple way to achieve my goal. Preferably even something that is only sending me a message when a node has crashed and therefore does not "clog" up the communication. Apparently (have not tested it yet) $rosnode list$ provides a list of all active nodes. I was wondering if I could periodically call this from within my .cpp-file (if I set the sampling rate low enough it should not interfere with other communication). I have seen that it is possible to do so for several other ROS commands that I usually only use in the terminal (find package path etc.).

What do you guys think?

Thanks,
Marcus

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/210212/simple-method-to-detect-node-crashes/) by [Marcus](https://answers.ros.org/users/11016/marcus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 164 on 2015-05-30

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think this is what the [bond](http://wiki.ros.org/bond) pkg is for.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-05-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Marcus](https://answers.ros.org/users/11016/marcus/) on 2015-05-30**:
Thank you,
I will check that out right away